# UIViewController does not deallocate, memory leak swift 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have single view app. UINavigationViewController have one root VC with button inside view. When pushVC pops from navigation stack it does not deallocate. RootVC btnClick function:

```
@IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: Any) {
    let vc = pushVC.init()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

pushVC have Notification Center subscription

```
class pushVC: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        Log()

        //this line brokes dealloc after pop from navigation stack
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "event_name"), object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
            self.printSomeText()
        }
    }

    deinit {
        Log()

    }

    func printSomeText() {
        Log()
    }
}


public func Log(filename: String = #file, line: Int = #line, funcname: String = #function) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss:SSS"
    let file = filename.components(separatedBy: "/").last!
    print("[\(dateFormatter.string(from:Date())) \(file)(\(line)) \(funcname)] ->")
}
```

log output: no deinit func called

```
[16:50:44:321 pushVC.swift(16) viewDidLoad()] ->
[16:50:53:938 pushVC.swift(16) viewDidLoad()] ->
[16:56:52:909 pushVC.swift(16) viewDidLoad()] ->
[16:56:54:248 pushVC.swift(16) viewDidLoad()] ->
[16:56:55:655 pushVC.swift(16) viewDidLoad()] ->
```

if remove self.printSomeText(), VC deinit called as expected.

```
[17:00:19:049 pushVC.swift(16) viewDidLoad()] ->
[17:00:20:136 pushVC.swift(25) deinit] ->
[17:00:20:746 pushVC.swift(16) viewDidLoad()] ->
[17:00:22:229 pushVC.swift(25) deinit] ->
[17:00:22:692 pushVC.swift(16) viewDidLoad()] ->
[17:00:23:938 pushVC.swift(25) deinit] ->
[17:00:24:493 pushVC.swift(16) viewDidLoad()] ->
[17:00:25:615 pushVC.swift(25) deinit] ->
```

What wrong with self.printSomeText() line?
Does it retain self?

Answer (score 1):

Update your `addObserver` to prevent the view controller from retaining itself…

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "event_name"), object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
        self?.printSomeText()
    }
}
```

You should also make the `Notification.Name` visible to other objects, remove the observer for your notification on `deinit`, and it's good practice to call `super.viewDidLoad()`…

```
extension NSNotification.Name {
    static let eventName = NSNotification.Name("event_name")
}

class pushVC: UIViewController {
    var observer: NSObjectProtocol?

    deinit {    
        if let observer = observer {
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .eventName, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
            self?.printSomeText()
        }
    }
}
```